# Where is the css file for Microsoft Identity scaffolding pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using Microsoft Identity to secure my web page. I'm scaffolding the login, logout and register pages. Now I want to style those pages but I don't know where the CSS file is. Anyone?

Comment: I don't feel those links give a straight forward answer. You have to dig it up from there. They talk more about general scaffolding than how to link to css files. From the first link I gather that I should put a .css file in the wwwroot/lib folder but that doesn't work...

Comment: Hi, can anyone re-open my question. I also need to know how to put a background image on the entire login page and the login page only gives me access to a part of the page, not the entire layout.

Comment: Actually never mind, I just figured it out myself.